# "sudo dmidecode" -> "/dev/mem: Operation not permitted"

Tags: 14.04, dmidecode

When running "sudo dmidecode" I get the following output:

```
johnny@johns-laptop:~$ sudo dmidecode
# dmidecode 2.12
# SMBIOS entry point at 0xa9e84010
/dev/mem: Operation not permitted
johnny@johns-laptop:~$
```

A search for this topic yielded only threads where requestor wanted to access /dev/mem as non-root, or was trying to do something much more complicated than this.

As a background - about 2 months ago my desktop wouldn't launch at all after a software update and I resolved it by creating another user and copying files over.  So it's possible I wasn't thorough enough when I set the new username up with root privileges...

I would describe my experience level as noob-ish.

sudoers file...

```
#
# This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root.
#
# Please consider adding local content in /etc/sudoers.d/ instead of
# directly modifying this file.
#
# See the man page for details on how to write a sudoers file.
#
Defaults        env_reset
Defaults        mail_badpass
Defaults        secure_path="/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin"

# Host alias specification

# User alias specification

# Cmnd alias specification

# User privilege specification
root    ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# Members of the admin group may gain root privileges
%admin ALL=(ALL) ALL

# Allow members of group sudo to execute any command
%sudo   ALL=(ALL:ALL) ALL

# See sudoers(5) for more information on "#include" directives:

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d


johnny@johns-laptop:~$ ls -l /dev/mem
crw-r----- 1 root kmem 1, 1 Dec 20 09:22 /dev/mem
johnny@johns-laptop:~$ lsattr /dev/mem
lsattr: Operation not supported While reading flags on /dev/mem
johnny@johns-laptop:~$ ^C
johnny@johns-laptop:~$
```

Comment: Can you add the content of `/etc/sudoers` to the question? You can do so by [edit]ing it.

Comment: Please edit your answer with the exact command you used.

Comment: What are the outputs of `ls -l /dev/mem` and `lsattr /dev/mem`? "not permitted" sounds like an extended attribute may be set

Comment: added those output to the question above.

Comment: can someone tell me how to paste the contents of an entire file into a question as a code block?  the 4 spaces doesn't work except for the first line, and neither does the single quotes.